# How to install DPDK kernel module?

Tags: dpdk

I have installed dpdk 18.08 on a Centos 7 machine, which has the kernel source installed.

I built dpdk using:

```
$ make -j T=x86_64-native-linuxapp-gcc install
<snip>
Build complete [x86_64-native-linuxapp-gcc]
Installation cannot run with T defined and DESTDIR undefined
```

I want to interface dpdk to a HP NIC that uses the Intel X722 chipset.  So I then run:

```
$ /opt/dpdk/dpdk-18.08/usertools/dpdk-devbind.py -b igb_uio `lspci | grep X722 | awk '{print $1}'`
Error - no supported modules(DPDK driver) are loaded
```

I think that this error means that the DPDK kernel module is not installed.

How can I fix this?

Comment: can you ensure igb_uio or vfio is loaded with `lsmod | grep uio`?  if it is not present please use `insmod`.  Please also cross-check the firmware used by referring https://doc.dpdk.org/guides/nics/i40e.html

Comment: Thank you, I have managed to install  igb_uio now and the driver is found.

Comment: congrats, can you close this one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comment interaction, the reason for missing Kernel Module. Installing `igb_uio` or `vfio-pci` has solved the problem.